# Pycharm showing warnings with SQLalchemy and query format

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pycharm

I'm using `sqlalchemy` in combination with `databases`, `databases[mysql]` and `aiomysql` to provide async access to the database. Pycharm shows a warning when constructing sqlalchemy queries. See the following example:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean, Table

users = Table(
    "user",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, index=True),
    Column("username", String(255), unique=True, index=True),
    Column("email", String(255), unique=True, index=True),
    Column("firstname", String(255), nullable=True),
    Column("lastname", String(255), nullable=True),
    Column("is_active", Boolean, default=True)

)


class User:

    @classmethod
    async def get(cls, username: str):
        query = users.select().where(users.c.username == username)
        user = await db.fetch_one(query)
        return user
```

The warning `Property 'c' cannot be read` appears at the line constructing the query. According to the [sqlalchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.c), this should be perfectly possible though.

Using the long form (`users.columns.username`) does not throw any warning.

Versions used:

- PyCharm 2020.2.3
- sqlalchemy 1.3.20

What is causing this warning, and is there a way go get rid of it?

Comment: I'm confused about the general setup. Why not define the columns in `User`?

Comment: @roganjosh I was essentially following the sqlalchemy guide (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html) which did It like that. How would I pass the metadata attribute to a class?